# Inserting Rows in MS Access using IF conditions

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have hourly data (24 hours) for each day for a year. Some hours are missing when there was no data. I need to insert a row with a value of zero when there was missing data to make sure each date has 24 hours of data. I am working in Access and working on VBAcode with SQL. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: How do you tell 1 hour apart from another in your data? E.g., is it something like 9/4/2012, 12:00:00 AM; 9/4/2012, 1:00:00 AM; etc?

Answer (score 0):

something like this would take your time, and check each time to see if it exists

```vb
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim datetime As Date
Dim stopdatetime As Date

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyData", dbOpenDynaset)

datetime = DateSerial(2011, 1, 1) + TimeSerial(9, 0, 0)
' #1/1/2011 @ 9AM
stopdatetime = DateSerial(2012, 1, 1)
' #1/1/2012 @ Midnight

While datetime < stopdatetime
    rs.FindFirst "MyDateTimeField=" & datetime ' formatting may be required
    If rs.NoMatch Then 
        'nomatch is true when time is not found, so add the missing record
        rs.AddNew
        rs!MyDateTimeField = datetime
        rs!Otherfileds = 0
        rs.Update
    End If
    datetime = datetime + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
    'add an hour
Wend
```